# Win32Native.Readfile waiting for synchronisation, a performance bottleneck?

Tags: winapi, synchronization, profiler, blocking, redgate

I profiled an application. Basically every thread reads an XML file from a network share, deserializes an object, logs to local files, asynchronously logs to db and calls a web service.
Amount of Threads is about 14 on a 24 core machine.

Redgate profiler shows me the multithreaded application is waiting for synchronisation 70% of the time. Is this an alarming signal or to be expected? Further if you can give advice how to approach analysing such a profiler log please share your knowledge.

[image: Profiler Log]

[image: Call graph]

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for synchronization just means that a thread is suspended while waiting for another thread to complete an operation. Whether or not you should be concerned about this depends on how long you expect the operation on that thread to take to reach completion.

If the stack indicates a read/write, then it may just mean the disk is slow, for example. Maybe you can minimize that by changing your code; maybe it's just a flaky network or disk drive.

Comment: The threads do not work together, parallel instead. I expected to see very little blocking of threads. Maybe its a slow file operation, like you said. As I have not much knowledge regarding profilers iam not sure this questions fully qualifies as proper SO material.In case this turns out to be a "well it depends" question ill take appropriate measures.